# Save and sort date and time in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, date, time, sql-order-by

I have a problem with this qoute:

```
SELECT _id, todo_name, todo_date_start, time_start FROM todo ORDER BY todo_date_start ASC
```

Is there an easy way to order my ToDos by the start-date (dd.mm.yyyy) and the start-time (hh:mm)?
It still works with the order by days of the date.

The table is created with text-format:

```
COLUMN_DATE_START + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_TIME_START + " text not null, "
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `by the start-date (dd.mm.yyyy) and the start-time (hh:mm)` The correct format is `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm` - Only **1** column is needed

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT _id, todo_name, todo_date_start, time_start FROM todo 
ORDER BY date(todo_date_start), time(time_start)  ASC
```

[sqlite date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: `ASC` can be omitted, since it's the **default**.